# Linux VM instance as a Gateway between two different subnets

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, routes

We have a requirement to create a VPN tunnel between 2 sites. one is my client's on-premise site which using cisco VPN gateway and another site in Google Cloud which managing by our team.

we have 2 subnets in our VPC network 192.168.1.0/24 (this range need reach via the VPN tunnel) and 192.168.10.0/24

**VPN tunnel needs to connect the following IP ranges:**

**Client end:**     10.10.0.0/24

**Our end:**        192.168.1.0/24 (web servers running)

But my client using our Internal Network ranges 192.168.1.0/24 on their side too. so we tried to NAT but unfortunately GCP Cloud NAT Feature cannot use with GCP Cloud VPN.

Considering that I have tested this scenario in my test environments with a new network range (172.10.10.X/24).

**Steps followed by me:**
Created a Linux VM instance as a Gateway which has two network interfaces (one interface(eth0) in 172.10.10.X/24 range and the other interface(eth1) in 192.168.1.0/24)

**VPN tunnel created between following IP ranges:**

**Client end:**     10.10.0.0/24

**Our end:**        172.10.10.X/24

I can ping to 172.10.10.X/24 range from 10.10.0.0/24 but cannot ping to 192.168.1.0/24 from 10.10.0.0/24

Hope I missed something here and need to add routing, can someone guide me with few steps?

Thanks

Comment: You or the client will need to remap their network addressing. Overlapped networks are not supported. There are exceptions if you have exceptionally good networking skills. For example, I have configured WireGuard for multiple point-to-point connections between overlapping networks, but I used special addressing for WireGuard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mentioned by @John Hanley in comment, overlapping networks are not supported.
You can only set up static routing in [specific scenarios](https://cloud.google.com/network-connectivity/docs/vpn/concepts/order-of-routes#example-subnet-interaction):

> Narrower than on-premises IP range
> (longer subnet mask)
>
> Google Cloud lets you create a custom static route with the 10.2.0.0/16 destination and next hop Cloud VPN tunnel; however, traffic to IP addresses in 10.2.99.0/24 remains inside your VPC network.

The best approach would be to re-address one of the networks.